# How can I copy cell values rather than references from one sheet to another in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How can I copy cell values rather than references from one sheet to another?  Right now using Filter, Query and ArrayFormula creates references which create empty cells and disallow sorting of the sheet.

I need the copy to only carry through values and not references.

Comment: Was the answer given, useful?

Answer (score 43):

You can copy the cell values and when pasting:

1. Right-click
2. Paste Special...
3. Paste values only

[image]

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly what I was looking to find out, and the added image makes it crystal clear.  Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to paste the value in another spreadsheet or in email, etc. Is there a solution to that problem? Note that I don't want to copy the displayed number, since it's rounded. I want to copy the actual result of the formula.

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+v` will paste values only.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is use the Paste Special command to paste into Google Sheets and then copy the newly pasted information to copy over to another spreadsheet or document. It adds a step but it is the only way I know to perform this action.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing a double step approach: I am copying from Google Sheets to Excel, then back to Google Sheets.
'Paste special' in Google Sheets transfers that information 2 times or 3 times & in a weird way!
I hope it will be fixed soon.

Comment: Thank you!  _This_ is exactly what I needed.  All the other highly rated "answers" only work within one sheet, and not across different sheets on different tabs in Chrome

Answer (score -3):

Pasting data values is NOT possible if the source cells are equations. Pasting data values only works if the source is TEXT data values. It's a frustrating limitation in Google Sheets.

Comment: Patently untrue. I do it all of the time.