# How do I copy cell values programatically?

Tags: google-sheets

How can I do this programmatically in Google Sheets?

[How can I copy cell values rather than references from one sheet to another in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33220/how-can-i-copy-cell-values-rather-than-references-from-one-sheet-to-another-in-g)

I have a RSS feed, that I am working along side, so I don't want to copy the reference to the other cell, rather the cell data, programatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to use [`Range.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()).

The following function takes a range `A2:B4`, and returns its pure values:

```
function getRangeValues() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:B4");
  var values = range.getValues();
  return values;
};
```

To use the script, you must first install it: In your spreadsheet, click *Tools -> Script editor*, and paste the script. From the drop-down menu in the Script Editor Toolbar, select *getRangeValues*, and click the *Run* button (you only need to do this once).
This will give you an authorization dialog, in which you must accept. From now on, you can use the function by entering `=getRangeValues()` in a cell.

See [the example spreadsheet I have set up](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o_HHaGHiR9Ci8NQwwjnC955Y_4BXzHxhlZPWruslmXw/edit?usp=sharing), and copy it to your own drive if you want to experiment with it.